# How to select a genetic distance range to plot a mst using vengan library

Tags: r, vegan

I've tried to perform a genetic distance analysis using ape and vegan. First of all I calculated genetic distances using ape:

```
data<-read.dna(file = "proof.txt", format = 'fasta')
D <- dist.dna(data, model ='TN93', as.matrix ='TRUE')
```

this code gives me a huge matrix with `d = 0` in many cases. Then, I perform the mst as follows:

```
mst <-spantree(distances, toolong = 0.015)
```

I chose `toolong` to select the max parwise distances = 0.015

But when I've tried to plot it, this error apeared:

> error in FUN 8d, y):zero or negative distances between objects 1 and 2

Does anyone know how to choose the distances larger than "0" and >= than 0.015?

Answer (score 0):

Supply a configuration on which to plot the spanning tree.

The error message comes from function `MASS::sammon()` that is used to find a configuration of points if none is given, and that function does not accept zero distances. For instance, the following should work:

```
plot(mst, ord = cmdscale(as.dist(dist.dna)))
```